# Is "though" in the following sentence used correctly?

Tags: word-usage, usage

> Though we do not know when she was born, we do not know where she is buried.

or is it wrong?

Comment: Did you mean "Though we do not know when she was born, we do know where she is buried."? If you truly mean you do not know either fact, though is not the correct word choice. Though is a word to contrast two things and there is not contrast when both thoughts are lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "though" here. Whenever you begin your sentence with "though"you immediately create an opposition between the first and the second part. But in your sentence it's impossible because both parts have negative meaning as it was stated by Ron.

Comment: Not impossible. Imagine there's a program and to qualify, among other strictures, you can't be a Spanish speaker. If you meet this qualification and are stil turned down for other reasons, you could say "Though I don't speak Spanish, I don't qualify for the program."

Answer (score 0):

It might make it easy to understand if you rephrase a sentence with "though" at the beginning and make it a sentence which uses "but". For example,

"***Though*** we do not know when she was born, we do not know where she is buried."

---> "We do not know when she was born, ***but*** we do not know where she is buried."

This way, you probably see why this sentence doesn't make sense as pointed out in Ron's comment. It is used incorrectly unless it is typed wrongly. Other examples are:

- *Though* he tried hard, nothing changed. ---> He tried hard, *but*
  nothing changed.
- *Though* Tom and Mary are twins, they don't look very similar. ---> Tom
  and Mary are twins, *but* they don't look very similar.
- *Though* Tom left home early today, he was late for work. ---> Tom left
  home early today, *but* he was late for work.